# How to pause and redirect in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing a code in express js that will post data and create a recorded. The record takes 1-3 seconds to get created, not sure of how long it will take. Is there a way that I can redirect to that record after that is created?

Here is my current code.

```
router.post("/recipePost", async (req, res) => {
  var body = req.body;
  var axios = require("axios");
  var data = JSON.stringify({
     "name":"john"
    });

  var config = {
    method: "post",
    url:
      "https://myEndpoint.com",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    data: data,
  };
  try {
    var resData = await axios(config);
    navigateToRec(resData.data.response.meta.id);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err");
  }
});
```

and my navigate method is as below.

```
navigateToRec = async (recId) => {
  console.log("recId" + recId);
  const resp = await axios.get(
    `https://myEndpoint.com/${recId}`
  );
  try {
    res.send({ redirect: "/recipeDetail/" + resData.data.response.meta.id });
  } catch (err) {
    this.navigateToRec(rec);
  }
};
```

Basically trying to call the same method till the record creation is a success. But here `console.log("recId" + recId);` is printing the Id created. Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Here is the error

> (node:83576) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed
> with status code 404
> at createError (/Users/rkeerthi/Desktop/Node js/yext-site/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
> at settle (/Users/rkeerthi/Desktop/Node js/yext-site/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
> at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/rkeerthi/Desktop/Node js/yext-site/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:293:11)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:412:35)
> at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1317:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created) (node:83576)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2) (node:83576) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

Comment: You're redirecting to route `/recipeDetail/:id`; where is that route defined? Can you share it here as a [mre] in context with the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes, make a POST request to server and await its completion and response. So I'll POST /do-job and server will do the job, when it's finished a code status 200 and response containing the new link will be sent. If user leaves they leave, anticipate for that lol.